# Magento 2.3.4 How to replace "Main Website Store" with my store name in the order confirmation email

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, admin-panel, order-confirmation-email

How do I change the text of the order confirmation email to our store name from Main Website Store? The answers that were already posted on SO are for Magento 1.

Comment: You can change Name of store from Store -> All stores (don't change code!)

Comment: I see the option to change the store name. Is it advisable to change the store name for all the stores, main website, main website store, default?

Comment: Yes, You can change name, NOT CODE

Comment: Done, it helped, thanks. You could convert the comment to answer so I will accept it. Others looking for the solution might benefit from it.

Comment: welcome :) Added Answer!

Comment: Could you please tell me if I can view the order confirmation email now without having to place a test order to check the content of the email?

Comment: If you have any older order, send email from admin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change Name of store from **Store -> All stores -> Select store name**
[image]

**Tip**: Don't change Store code!